# PHP - File upload - What is happening internally?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, file-io

For image upload  we use FILE html controller.

How this html controller able to browse in the local system?

After selecting a file , it will be copied and moved to server location.

If the php is ale to copy the local file and move to server , will it be able to do any other manipulations of that file ? like delete!

What is happening actually on file upload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML control is provided by the browser. The browser is a local application and has access to the user's file system. The file's contents are sent to the receiving script by the browser using [standard methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

PHP has no access to the user's file system at any point, just the copy provided by the browser. Deleting or even reading files on the user's file system is not possible.

Comment: nice answer and good link.  i was thinking to make a system hacking tool using php :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually php is not accessing local system. After you choose a file and click upload at upload form. The whole file(not location) is sent via POST request. And php just recieves that POST request with the whole file, and stores at server.

Comment: :-) if it is post , then why using $_FILE

Comment: @zod the data is POST data internally. PHP just parses them into `$_FILE` and turns them into temporary files for convenience